# Alfresco Exception caused by MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry ... etc

Tags: mysql, exception, glassfish, alfresco, cluster-computing

I have a glassfish 3.1.1 web server, and I create 2 instances on it, I deploy Alfresco Explorer 3.4e and everything was going well in one instance, but when I try to start the other instance, I got error and the alfresco in that instance not working.

**My settings & Specs of Env. are :**

- JDK 1.7
- Glassfish 3.1.1
- Cluster Environment created with glassfish ***(have 2 instance on
  the same machine)***
- MySQL : Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.52, for Win64
- Alfresco Explorer 3.4e (I got war file from webapps folder of
  tomcat bundled version)
- Windows 7 64bit !!

**The exception is:**

```
glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|14:07:26,077  ERROR [web.context.ContextLoader] Context initialization failed
org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 07150002 Failed to write property deltas: 

.
.
.

Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: SqlMapClient operation; SQL ;   
--- The error occurred in alfresco/ibatis/#resource.dialect#/node-common-SqlMap.xml. 
--- The error occurred while applying a parameter map. 
--- Check the alfresco.node.parameter_NodeProperty. 
--- Check the statement (update failed). 
--- Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '542-69--1-2' for key 'PRIMARY'; nested exception is com.ibatis.common.jdbc.exception.NestedSQLException:
```

My reference of configurations:

- http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_on_Glassfish
- http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Cluster_Configuration_V2.1.3_and_Later
- [http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Category:High_Availability](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Category%3aHigh_Availability)

**Note:** This exception logged in the second instance that unable to run because this exception, but the first instance is working, if I shutdown the first and restart the second, the exception will not happen and the instance will run without problems.

**You can see full details of my problem & my Configuration here**: http://forums.alfresco.com/en/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=40252&p=118012#p118012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Think the problem was that when i start 2 instances on the same time on "New & Clean" schema that cause this problem, Now after I stop all instances, start first one, then shutdown it, then change "Quick Server" & "Vti" ports of second instance, then start 2 instances at the same time, the two instances running successfully.

Please note that 2nd instance can have his own property file in Glassfish 3.1.1 but in Glassfish 2.1.1 you will unable to do that.

And If you restart 2nd instance with "--sync full" you need to reset the ports again and restart 2nd instance again, somehow I think the port can be set in domain.xml file and call it from property file, so each instance save it alone and "--sync full" will not be a problem.

Regards,